# PHP Remove Pound Sign (£) from price

Tags: php

I have price value which has pound sign in front of it. I need to remove that sign.

```
$price = '£3.76' (This comes from database and is stored as a string within the database)

1) preg_replace('/[\£]/', '', $price);
2) ltrim($price, '£');
3) str_replace(utf8_decode("£"),"",utf8_decode($price));
4) str_replace('£', '', $price);
```

I tried to use everything about but nothing worked. 1 and 4 replaces with Â and 2 and 3 adds Â to the left of the value. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Which of the above commands yields the output you're seeing? Please post the complete string containing the price value as example so we've got a real world example to assist you with.

Comment: I have edited the question now please let me know if it is more clear now.

Comment: If you're seeing `Â`, in the browser, it is because the content-type character encoding being sent by the server is incorrect.  You can add `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to your script to see the pound sign properly.  But `$price = str_replace('£', '', $price);` works fine for me to remove it.

Comment: Also check and make sure the database is utf-8 Collation

Comment: @drew010 I am exporting data in csv file and I am seeing Â in the file.

Comment: This means the CSV needs to be saved in UTF-8 encoding, it is being interpreted as ascii, probably ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @drew010 I tried to save the file in UTF-8 encoding by adding fputs($affiliate_data_file, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) )); However now the sign is replaced with random characters such as '±' , ¶ etc. All I want to do is remove the sign from the string completely before exporting it to csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar situation. Try the following code:

```
$amount = "$500";

echo substr($amount,1,strlen($amount)); // returns "500"
```

Comment: Since the pound sign is not ASCII, it uses 2 bytes, so mb_substr will need to be used.

Comment: @drew010 I have used mb_substr for now to replace the first character. However I still dont think this is the right solution as it may be possible that the pound sign is not present in the string

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, solved it using mb_strpos to search for the £ and then I used mb_substr to join the characters up to the pos to pos + 1. This removed the £ and didn't leave the Â. Your solution steered me in the right direction so hopefully this will help you determine if the string has a £.